# How to mock a single utility function globally using jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

Suppose in my util.js I have

```
export function foo(){ ... do something}
export function bar(){ ... do something}
...
```

And in various components I utilize foo

```
//Foo1.component.js

import { foo } from './util'A

... do something using foo.
```

```
//Foo2.component.js

import { foo } from './util'A

... do something using foo.
```

etc..

How can I go about mocking this, in `Foo1.test.js` for example.

Even better, is there way that I can just 'hijack' this `foo` import maybe from the jest.config.
in the `moduleNameMapper` Maybe?

So that it is already mocked for all tests `Foo1.test.js` and `Foo2.test.js`?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is a way to mock modules in test environment.

If you want to mock the modules in specific test files, you can try just the `jest.mock()` function. For example, mocking the `foo` method in `Foo1.component.js` test file would go like this:

```
// Foo1.component.test.js

jest.mock('./path/to/utils.js', () => ({
  foo: () => { // custom implementation for test env }
  bar: () => { // custom implementation for test env if needed }
}));

// The foo imported below has the custom implementation for test env
import { foo } from './util';
```

The other option is to create a mock module, I think this better suite your need. In the folder where `utils.js` is located, create a `__mocks__` folder, under which you would add a file `utils.js`(the same name as the module to be mocked), in that file, you can compose the mock behavior for the `util.js` module. For example:

```
// __mocks__/utils.js
export function foo(){ ... mock implementation}
export function bar(){ ... mock implementation}
```

Whenever you need those mock implementation in your test files, just call the the `jest.mock` method with the path to the module. For example:

```
// Foo1.component.test.js

jest.mock('./path/to/utils.js');

// The foo imported below has the custom implementation for test env
import { foo } from './util';
```

Links:

- [Using `jest.mock`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestmockmodulename-factory-options)
- [Creating mock modules](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks#mocking-user-modules)

Comment: I think I wasn't clear enough when describing. My utils.js file is quite large, and I wanted to avoid having to mock all of them. The implementation above seem to require me to do so. Would it still work if I just have a mock `foo` and what ever it doesnt find will it refer to the original util.js?